# CSS animation from center to specific location

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I'm trying to write a CSS-based transition that moves text from horizontal center to a specific distance from the left of the page. My current CSS looks like this (target is div with text and class 'title' + 'anim'):

```
.title {
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.anim {
  animation: translate-title 2s linear;
}

@keyframes translate-title {
  0% {
    min-width: 100%;
    left: 0px;
  }

  100% {
    min-width: 0;
    left: 50px;
  }
}
```

The issue with the code above is that min-width of 0 is less than the actual arbitrary width of the text and thus the shift left due to the 'min-width' completes before the the shift to the right due to 'left' completes. The net result is an apparent bounce which I would like to remove.

see it for chrome/ff at http://jsfiddle.net/62tQE/4/

Can anyone think of a solution that doesn't involve using js?

Comment: the bounce looks cool

Comment: if the bounce were bigger it would be even cooler...lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I removed the `left` from the animation and added `padding` and `box-sizing` to `.title`:

```css
.title {
    position: absolute;
    min-width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    width: auto;
    padding: 0 50px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.anim {
    -webkit-animation: translate-title 2s linear;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation: translate-title 2s linear;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes translate-title {
    0% {
        min-width: 100%;
    }
    100% {
        min-width: 0;
    }
}
@keyframes translate-title {
    0% {
        min-width: 100%;
    }
    100% {
        min-width: 0;
    }
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/62tQE/5/)**

Comment: While this answered my question -- turns out the end solution wont end up suiting my needs after all. It looks like animating using min-width is  very choppy on a IOS 6 and IOS 7 (beta 5) webview. I'll likely end going with js-aided (for calculating exact positions) css-based transitions as using transitioning the 'left' of '.table' as it is much smoother. Not as elegant as pure CSS transitions but the perf improvement is worth it.

Comment: You could try using transforms. Anything thing that requires a repaint is going to be a bit choppy on iOS, since it can't be offloaded to the GPU.